# How to add image behind header in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to add image behind the header but how can I do that ? I have made header transparent but now I want to place the image below it (See screenshot 1). I also tried to add `position: 'absolute' and top,bottom,left,right` for image but it doesn't work why so ?

Code:

```
screen: ProjectDetailsScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            headerTitle: navigation.state.params.title,
        }),
```

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Comment: brother please try my solution!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the **mix of zIndex and Position in styles** !

like in the manner of this!

1:     make the header as

```
screen: ProjectDetailsScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerStyle: {
            position:'relative',
            zIndex: 1
        },
      headerTransparent: true
    })
    // this will cause header on the top and make the rest of design in below part
     lowerViewContainerStyle:{
            position:'absolute',
            zIndex: 0
     }
```

Comment: If I try to add top, left, right, bottom, position: 'absolute' inside headerStyles it gives warning saying it has no effect on headerStyles so it is not working. So `headerTransparent: true` works fine.

Comment: the position and zIndex help to put the image behind the header and also the lower header on top index!

Comment: Can you please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132013/how-to-close-modal-in-react-native

Answer (score 1):

Adding `headerTransparent: true` inside navigationOptions solved the problem.

Code:

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({    
      headerTransparent: true
})
```